# Sending a contact .vcf file

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments, android-bluetooth, android-sharing

i want to send a contact vcf file using the bluetooth and email. I have tried but i keep getting errors. Please help. Thanks

This is my sendByBluetooth method.

```
public void sendByBluetooth(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();  
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
    intent.setType("image/png");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(storage_path) );  
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is my emailContact method.

```
public void emailContact() {     
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    // Add attributes to the intent 
    sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject line"); 
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Body of email"); 
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(storage_path))); 
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email"); 

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Email:"));       

}
```

Please Help! Thanks.

Comment: Why do you `intent.setType("image/png");` ?

Comment: I do not know what setType() to use

Answer (score 2):

For bluetooth you can set the type as `intent.setType("text/x-vcard");`

```
public void sendByBluetooth(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();  
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
    intent.setType("text/x-vcard");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(storage_path) );  
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and for emails you could use

```
String filelocation="/mnt/sdcard/contacts.vcf";    
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// set the type to 'email'
emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
String to[] = {"asd@gmail.com"};
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
// the attachment
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, filelocation);
// the mail subject
emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
```

Just a side note: The.vcf file should be in in your SD card