# android.os.FileUriExposedException: exposed beyond app through Intent.getData() Exception , While sharing VCFile

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, vcf-vcard

**Problem Statement**

> I am trying to make VCardfile, and It is successfully created but, I Want to share created file

**Exception**

> android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/vcf_demonuts/android_1633671182515.vcf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

**MY Code**

```
            var vdfdirectory = File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + VCF_DIRECTORY
            );
            // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
            if (!vdfdirectory.exists()) {
                vdfdirectory.mkdirs();
            }

            vcfFile =
                File(vdfdirectory, "android_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".vcf");

            val fw: FileWriter = FileWriter(vcfFile);
            fw.write("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
            fw.write("VERSION:3.0\r\n");
            // fw.write("N:" + p.getSurname() + ";" + p.getFirstName() + "\r\n");
            fw.write("FN:" + "Sibtain" + "\r\n");
            //  fw.write("ORG:" + p.getCompanyName() + "\r\n");
            //  fw.write("TITLE:" + p.getTitle() + "\r\n");
            fw.write("TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" + "+923155022905" + "\r\n");
            //   fw.write("TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:" + p.getHomePhone() + "\r\n");
            //   fw.write("ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;" + p.getStreet() + ";" + p.getCity() + ";" + p.getState() + ";" + p.getPostcode() + ";" + p.getCountry() + "\r\n");
            fw.write("EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:" + "abc@gmail.com" + "\r\n");
            fw.write("END:VCARD\r\n");
            fw.close();


            val txtIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            txtIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(vcfFile), "text/x-vcard");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(txtIntent, "Share"))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**I have to Try following*&[solution available on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726084/sending-a-contact-vcf-file)

**I have created a provider_path.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Manifest**

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.testapp.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below code it works for sharing VCFile:**

```
 private void shareContact(ContactsModal modal) {

    String lookupKey = null;
    Cursor cur = ((Activity)context).getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]
            { ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY },
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = " + modal.getContactID(), null, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
         lookupKey = cur.getString(0);
    }
    if(lookupKey!=null){
        Uri vcardUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_TYPE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, vcardUri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Contact Name");
        ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In the `onCreate` method your application file. Place the following code

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

This will make the exception go away. However, this is used mostly as a diagnostic tool and it not a proper solution.

Another solution with the fileProvider method would be to add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag to your intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, f));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Yes your solution helps to go away exception but I am still unable to share .vcf formate file using Intent.Will you please explain how we can share .vcf file